# Error migrating app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to migrate my app to heroku and this error came up, causing a rollback of my migration. Can anyone tell me why is there an error with date_time?

```
remembrance:~/rails_project/alpha-blog (master) $ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ alpha-blog-javier... up, run.4829
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddDescriptionToArticles (20160816052220)
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20160816052220 AddDescriptionToArticles: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:articles, :description, :text)
   (2.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "description" text
   -> 0.0024s
-- add_column(:articles, :created_at, :date_time)
   (4.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "created_at" date_time
   (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "date_time" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "created_at" date_time
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be `datetime` not `date_time`. Read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
add_column(:articles, :created_at, :date_time)
```

in your migration to

```
add_column(:articles, :created_at, :datetime)
```